# Match and paste value from one sheet into another based on a Lookup value

Tags: excel, vba

i have two sheets, Bills and Reconciliation, Both have Bill ID in column B. what i need is a vba code which will copy values from Column P,Q and W of Reconciliation sheet and paste these values in Column P,Q And W of Sheet Bills against same Bill ID.  In Sheet Reconciliation Bill Id starts from Row21 and can be dynamic, so last row function will be used. in sheet Bills Bill id starts from B2 and can go till B100000 Or more

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsDisp As Worksheet: Set wsDisp = wb.Worksheets("Reconciliation")


Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim e As Long
Dim F As String




 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 a = wsDisp.Cells(19, 16).Value
 b = wsDisp.Cells(19, 17).Value
 c = wsDisp.Cells(19, 23).Value


e = MsgBox("Do You Wish to Save Recovery ? " & vbNewLine & "GIDC PAID = " & a & vbNewLine & "GST PAID = " & b & vbNewLine & " LPS PAID = " & c, vbYesNo)


If e = vbNo Then Exit Sub



   For i = 21 To 400
   
    
       Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 16) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 16)
       Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 17) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 17)
       Sheets("Bills").Cells(Cells(i, 2), 23) = Sheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 23)

    

  Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Reconciliation sheet

[image]

Bills sheet

[image]

Comment: What problem do you have with the code you show? Does it raise an error? If yes, what error, on which line? If not, what (not) does it against what you need?

Comment: Can't you just use the VLOOKUP function? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation and have this solution that works for me, i use VLookup in this case if Bill NR are ascending.

You can make record macro to get VLookup and use this copy function to get values in your sheet.

```
Range("P21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Reconciliation shee!R2B1:R10000P5,5,FALSE)"
    Range("P21").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P21:P" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("P21:P" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```